# Register value - MIPS

Tags: programming-languages, mips

The language is MIPS.

```
$s2 = 0x00000046   ;   $s1 = 0x000038c
```

What will be the $s2 value in Hex after the following code ? :

```
add $s2, $s1, $s2
srl $s1, $s1, 4
or  $s2, $s1, $s2
```

Can some one show me the way ?

thnx !

Comment: It depends on what values you have in s1, s2 prior to these instructions.

Comment: $s2 = 0x00000046   ;   $s1 = 0x000038c

Comment: OK - so take it one instruction at a time - what will the values be after the first `add` ?

Comment: the value after first line will be 0x46 ?

Comment: You're adding s2 = 0x46 and s1 = 0x38c and putting the result in s2. So s1 will be unchanged, and s2 will be ?...

Comment: I typed in a fx-570ms in base mode Hex, the following: 38C + 46
and I get 46 ...

Comment: Basic math should tell you that 0x38C + 0x46 can't be 0x46 - I make it 0x3D2.

Comment: I tried to do it handy... will it be 3D2 ?

Comment: and what should srl do ?

Comment: Take a look at a MIPS instruction set reference online, e.g. http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html or http://www.mips.com/media/files/MD00565-2B-MIPS32-QRC-01.01.pdf - SRL is Shift Right Logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to describe what each instruction does, e.g. in pseudo code, or here in C:

```
add $s2, $s1, $s2  # s2 = s1 + s2;
srl $s1, $s1, 4    # s1 = s1 >> 4;
or  $s2, $s1, $s2  # s2 = s1 | s2;
```

Comment: after srl it will be 0x38c0000 ??

Comment: @Adam D: no, it's a *right* shift by 4 *bits*. So `s1 = 0x38c >> 4 = 0b001110001100 >> 4 = 0b000000111000 = 0x38`.

Comment: and the or logic means if one of the both according bits is "1" the result will be also "1" ?

Comment: @Adam D: yes, it's a *bitwise* OR, so for each corresponding bit in the two input registers you set the corresponding output bit if either of the two input bits is 1. Only if both input bits at that position are 0 will the output bit then be 0.

Comment: @Adam D: yes, the last instruction is equivalent to `s2 = s1 | s2;`, which means the final result is in `s2`.

Comment: Paul.. the final value of $s2 is 0x3FA ??